# Regular Expression to Match a String that contains non-repetitive words

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I'm working on a regular expression where I need to verify a input text that contains 4 distinct words separated by a comma.

> input text words: - one, two, three, four. Each of these words should not be repeated more than once. 
>   so, it can be: two, three, four, one or three, four, two, one and not one, one, one, one

Here is what I wrote and found a partial solution by doing separate searches

```
^\b(one|two|three|four)\b?,\b(one|two|three|four)\b?,\b(one|two|three|four)\b?,\b(one|two|three|four)\b
```

But the problem with solution is words are getting repeated, and the test for "one, one, one, one" fails.

Can you please let me know how to avoid the duplicates and where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: Your desire to use regex here reminds me of the aphorism "When the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."  Learn parsing.

Comment: u should provide more valid-invalid text..

Answer (score 1):

It would be far easier to NOT do this particular problem with a single regular expression.

First off, `\b` is zero-width.  So you do not need to follow it using a `?`, your intention is probably `\s?`.

Next, regex is pretty much stateless, in the general case, which means that you'd need to construct your regex as follows.

```
^\s*(one\s*,(two\s*,(three\s*,four|four\s*,three)|three\s*,(two\s*,four|four\s*,two)...
```

As you can see, you have to manually deal with combinatoric explosion.  Which is far less than ideal.

You should instead, split on `,` and use java to check.

> Thanks for replying. From what i understand, you want me not use regex rather use java.can you detail a bit on how to check in java

Try this (untested code, will be bugs):

```
public parseList(String input) {
  String[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
  bool foundNumbers = { false, false, false, false };
  String delims = "\s*,";
  String[] tokens = input.split(delims);

  if (tokens.length != 4) {
    //deal with error case as you wish
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; ++j) {
      if (numbers[i].equals(tokens[j])) {
        if (!foundNumbers[i]) {
          foundNumbers[i] = true;
        } else {
          //deal with error case as you wish
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < foundNumbers.length; ++i) {
    if (!foundNumbers[i]) {
      //deal with error case as you wish
    }
  }

  //success
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for replying. From what i understand, you want me not use regex rather use java.can you detail a bit on how to check in java..

Comment: Added some (likely buggy, probably doesn't compile) code to the answer.  It could be made better, if I knew more about what your actual requirements are.

Comment: Actually, better use [Tim Yate's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110505/483486) he knows more about Java than I do. :)

Comment: @omnipotent mine's in groovy, as it saves you writing code ;-)

Comment: You don't need to manually deal with the combinatoric explosion, the regex engine can do it for you (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean valid( String input ) {
  input.tokenize( ',' ).with { list ->
    list.unique( false ) == list &&
      list.every { it in ['one','two','three','four'] }
  }
}
```

should do it without regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use regex?

Just split the text on comma and do your usual array / list duplicate check

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use regular expressions to parse a non regular input. In this case, the input is more like a context free language. I recommend tokenizing the string and counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookaheads in this way (see at [Regexr](http://regexr.com?32k60)):

```rb
\b(one|two|three|four)\b,             # match one of the allowed words
\b(?!\1)(one|two|three|four)\b,       # match one of them but not first matched one
\b(?!\1|\2)(one|two|three|four)\b,    # match one of them but not first and second matched ones
\b(?!\1|\2|\3)(one|two|three|four)\b  # match one of them but not first, second and third matched ones
```

Comment: .thank you for your time and solution. this regex would expect input string to always contain 4 words[one,two,three,four] words,kind of an AND. My input string could  contain one word or 2 words or 3 words or 4 words,kind of OR. For eg., input string could be "one" or "one,two" or "three,two,one" or "four,three,one two" but should always be from the [one,two,three,four] .

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not use a regex for this. You can, though:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches(
    "(?x)                            # Verbose regex                        \n" +
    "(?:                             # Match...                             \n" +
    " (?:one()|two()|three()|four()) #  one of the four words               \n" +
    " (?:\\s*,\\s*|\\s*$)            #  a comma or end-of-string            \n" +
    "){4}                            # four times                           \n" +
    "$                               # End of string                        \n" +
    "\\1\\2\\3\\4                    # Assert that all four words have matched");
```

The empty capturing groups ensure (together with `\1\2\3\4` at the end) that each word participates exactly once in the match :)